# Camera is not centering between 2 gameobjects correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button that makes the MainCamera switch between being in the middle of several objects.

For example, there's the [StartPoint , CheckPoint , CheckPoint , EndPoint]

I want the camera to switch continuously across the checkpoints like the comma between the checkpoints. ^^

This code is the actual switching the position placing for the MainCamera **(where the error might be)**

```
public void SwitchCameraBetween(GameObject nextPoint, GameObject afterNextPoint)
{
    Vector3 centerPoint = (afterNextPoint.transform.position - nextPoint.transform.position) / 2;
    centerPoint.z = -10;

    float cameraSize = (afterNextPoint.transform.position - nextPoint.transform.position).magnitude - nextPoint.transform.localScale.x;

    mainCamera.transform.position = centerPoint;
    mainCamera.orthographicSize = cameraSize / 3;
}
```

> The camera switches perfect for the first 2 checkpoints (either StartPoint & EndPoint or StartPoint & CheckPoint) after the camera stays in same position or off by a couple values. I checked by using Debug.Log(); to see if the camera has the correct gameobjects between and it does so why does it not work?

Comment: You're sorting your game objects by transform index. Are you sure the start point and end point are still at the beginning and end of your list, respectively, after the sort? See what happens when you move the sort before the insert/add.

Comment: yes I checked, list in correct order, moving across correctly

Comment: Is it the math? Isn't the center point between two points something like this (for one dimension): `centerPoint = x2 - ((x2 - x1) / 2)`? For example, the center between 10 and 2 is 6, yet your formula would produce 4.

Comment: `center = (a + b) / 2`, not `(a - b) / 2` Could also use `Vector3.Lerp(a, b, 0.5f)` for readability, if desired.

Comment: @cwharris that was it thank you! wow such a dumb mistake

Comment: @NathanA thank you as well!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center point should be the average of all points, so you need to add your points, not subtract them, and then divide the result by the number of points included for the average.

`center = sum(points) / count(points)`, so `center = (a + b) / 2`

Alternatively, you could use `Vector3.Lerp(a, b, 0.5f)` if you find that more readable, although *technically* this would be slower, since it's both a method call and more operations, unless the compiler is doing fancy things behind the scenes...

Comment: The slower part may not be true, Lerp is a minus operation plus a multiplication (multiplication can be faster on chip traditionally than division). There is a clamp check on the last parameter in there so Vector3.LerpUnclamped may be faster.

Comment: The operator overloads + and / of vector3 are all method calls btw, operator overloads just provide syntax sugar for classes to provide a nicer experience.

Comment: Sure. It’s still more calculations, though. The compiler will handle trivial optimizations such as `/ 2` vs `* 0.5` vs `>> 2`. Might even in-line the operators/methods. Might even be smart enough to convert the `lerp(a, b, 0.5)` to `(a + b) * 0.5` via static analysis. Who knows. Still good practice, IMO, to consider these things (albeit briefly) especially if you’re a polyglot where some of your languages might not have good compilers.